# Why can't I use a vertex group to control a particle system's density?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, particles, vertex-groups

Even with *Use Modifier Stack* turned on, and the Particle System being above the Subdivision Surface Modifier my Particle Systems Vertex Group Density isn't working.

I'm trying to apply a Vertex Group to the Particle Systems Density, but it seems that every time I do so, the particles seems to group up in one place and completely ignore the Vertex Group.

Example CloseUp (click to see full image):

[image: Example Image CloseUp]

So if anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I guess I was supposed to assign the vertex group in the particle system, **while not** in *Edit Mode*. So make sure you create a vertex group and then apply that vertex group in the density panel in the particle systems under Vertex Groups. And make also sure you aren't in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: That's strange if it didn't work for you. You can *assign* a vertex group to the density in Particle System settings > **Vertex Groups** rollout. You can't *see the effect* of the vertex group's assignment - it will be refreshed once you switch to Object mode.

Comment: Four years later and it's still useful